# Input radio en alert()/confirm()/prompt() jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera saber si es posible lanzar un `alert()`, `confirm()` o `prompt()` con `<input type="radio">`y obtener el valor seleccionado después de pulsar el típico "Aceptar" que sale en los `alert()`, `confirm()` o `prompt()`convencionales.

Estuve buscando por todas partes no encontré nada. Me parece difícil que nadie haya pensado en esto.

Comment: Un mockup, si es que no tienes código, ayudaría mucho para ayudarte a desarrollar esa funcionalidad, o si ya tienes algo hecho, pon el código, es difícil entenderte ya que se presta tu pregunta a estar basada en opiniones y podría ser cerrada.

Comment: Para esos casos yo uso las modales de bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pides no se puede hacer en un alert/confirm/prompt, además es una mala práctica usar estos elementos porque bloquean el navegador.

Existen alternativas como crear una ventana modal por ejemplo con bootstrap. Puedes ver cómo se usa aquí en la documentación oficial de Bootstrap: [Modales con Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal)

No te pongo aquí cómo hacerlo porque el tema es diferente a lo que tú preguntas y no tiene sentido contestarte aquí, por eso te pongo un enlace para que puedas consultar tú mismo la documentación y en caso de que no te aclares podrás crear aquí una pregunta nueva con el código que te de problemas y así te podremos ayudar.

Un saludo.

Comment: Los aportes que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad, considera leer [answer]

Comment: Pues no sé por qué, porque en este caso está justificado: Ofrece contexto para los enlaces
Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudará a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porqué decidiste añadirlos. Procura siempre citar la parte más relevante del enlace por si la página web desaparece o es cambiada en un futuro.

Comment: Correcto, pero como te he dicho en otra parte no me parece lógico ponerle un código totalmente nuevo que no tiene relación con el código expuesto por él. Que piense él el algoritmo y si tiene dudas que pregunte de nuevo.

Comment: Por eso yo se lo puse en un comentario y no como respuesta ;)

Comment: Me parece que esto debería ser un comentario, lejos de ser una respuesta, ya que solo sugieres, además de que en principio la pregunta carece de contexto y está basada en opiniones.

Comment: Gracias @alexval me ha servido mucho lo de los Modales de Bootstrap.